# How can I use Parse LiveQuery for Android to automatically add new objects to my RecyclerAdapter?

Tags: android, json, parse-platform, gson, parse-server

I'm using LiveQuery for Parse Android to listen for events, i.e. the creation of an object. When the object is created, I want to add it to the beginning of my list. The listening part seems to be working but I'm not sure exactly what to do with the JSON object that is received. In particular, I'm following this tutorial and using Back4App as a host: https://docs.back4app.com/docs/android/live-query/

**Gradle:**

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
compile 'com.github.tgio:parse-livequery:1.0.3'
```

I have an Async task that runs the network operation on a separate thread and is able to retrieve the desired JSON objects:

```
private class UpdateTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(final String... string) {
        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "ASYNC");

        // Subscription
        final Subscription sub = new BaseQuery.Builder("Message")
                .build()
                .subscribe();

        Log.e(getClass().getName(), String.valueOf(sub.isSubscribed()));

        sub.on(LiveQueryEvent.CREATE, new OnListener() {
            @Override
            public void on(final JSONObject object) {
                Log.e(getClass().getName(), object.toString());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("JSONObject" + object.toString());
                        // {"op":"create","clientId":13,"requestId":0,"object":{"conversationObject":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Conversation","objectId":"lZsj4dPCvb"},"messageText":"What's your phone number?","author":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"2E0bbd3oSD"},"createdAt":"2017-09-15T15:40:39.303Z","updatedAt":"2017-09-15T15:40:39.303Z","__type":"Object","className":"Message","objectId":"7A4RHttAEr"}}

                        // TODO: Take JSON object, convert to POJO, add to mMessages, notify data adapter
                        String mJsonString = object.toString();
                        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
                        JsonElement mJson =  parser.parse(mJsonString);
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        Message object2 = gson.fromJson(mJson, Message.class);

                        mMessages.add(0, object2);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                });
            }
        });

        return null;
    }

}
```

I call this Async task after an object is created, simply:

```
message.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
 @Override
 public void done(ParseException e) {

  // Listen for messages and update UI
  new UpdateTask().execute();
 }
});
```

My message class looks like this (I'm using Kotlin, but otherwise doesn't make a difference):

```
@ParseClassName("Message")
class Message : ParseObject() {

    /* Message Pointers */
    val author by ParseDelegate<ParseObject>()
    val contact by ParseDelegate<Contact>()

    /* Message Content */
    val messageText by ParseDelegate<String>()

}
```

With the JSON object, I should be able to convert it into a version of my local object and then append it to the list, and I've shown my attempt above, but the object doesn't appear after creating it. I still have to refresh.

Worse, every couple times I get this error:

```
09 - 16 12: 05: 13.907 10004 - 10004 / com.sourcey.materialloginexample E / AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.sourcey.materialloginexample, PID: 10004
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void java.util.List.add(int, java.lang.Object)'
on a null object reference
at com.sourcey.materiallogindemo.activity.MessageActivity$UpdateTask$1$1.run(MessageActivity.java: 213)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java: 751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 776)
```

I figure the error is that the local Object is not created from the JSON properly, i.e., when I print `Log.e(getClass().toString(), object2.getMessageText());` I get:

```
09 - 16 12: 15: 31.741 20252 - 20252 / com.sourcey.materialloginexample E / AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.sourcey.materialloginexample, PID: 20252
java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
at android.util.Log.e(Log.java: 236)
at com.sourcey.materiallogindemo.activity.MessageActivity$UpdateTask$1$1.run(MessageActivity.java: 213)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java: 751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 776)
```

**Object Debug:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please use the official liveQuery client from android.
[ParseLiveQueryAndroid](https://github.com/parse-community/ParseLiveQuery-Android)

Instead of getting a JSON object, you get a ParseObject